# How to dynamically insert a template into another template

Tags: vue.js

New to VueJS... I have a component that I want to pass other components into based on the selection made in a dropdown. I have a main template that will always be rendered on the screen, part of which has a dropdown. When I make a selection in that dropdown I want to have a div inside that main component with an ID (or some other identifying property) and push another template inside of it. I'm thinking that a `slot` does the opposite of what I want..

Original Template:

```
<div class="search-field-with-label-container">
    <el-select v-model="serviceType">
      <el-option
        v-for="serviceType in serviceTypes"
        :key="serviceType.id"
        :value="serviceType"
      >{{ serviceType }}</el-option>
    </el-select>
    <div id="thisIsWhereIWantMyOtherTemplateToRender"
  </div>
```

Second template:

```
<template>
  <h1>this is the other template</h1>
</template>
```

Comment: import it as component

Comment: Sure, ok. But let's say I have 7 different dropdown options and seven other templates I want to conditionally render. Is the correct way to do this to just list them all, and conditionally render them based on some kind of data binding?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic components with the keep-alive tag.

```
    <keep-alive>
      <component v-bind:is="selectedComponent"></component>
    </keep-alive>
```

Documentation is [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html).